# PHP Form Action - Post to PHP File Based on Form Selection?

Tags: php

I have a standard PHP form. When the form is submitted, a PHP "mailer" file sends the user a "thank you" e-mail and redirects the user to a "thank you" page. I'd like to add a drop-down menu to the form and have different "mailer" files associated with each drop-down option. In other words, the drop-down option selected determines which "mailer" file is used...each mailer file has a different "thank you" e-mail text and different "thank you" page URL. Can this be done with PHP, or does this need a custom script?

For reference, I've included the relevant parts of the form file and mailer file:

PHP FORM

```
    <form  action="https://example.com/mailer.php" method="post" >

    <label for="name">
    <span>Name:</span>
    <input type="text" id="name"  name="name">
    </label>

    <label for="dropdown">
    <span>Which of the following:</span>
    <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown"  >
    <option label=""></option>
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    </label>

    <label for="email">
    <span>E-mail:</span>
    <input type="text" id="email"  name="email">
    </label>

    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"><b>SUBMIT</b></button>
    </form>
```

PHP MAILER FILE

```
    // FORM SUBMISSION EMAIL ADDRESS
    $mailto = 'example@example.com' ;

    // FORM SUBMISSION EMAIL SUBJECT
    $from = "subject" ;

    // FORM SUBMISSION THANK YOU PAGE REDIRECT */
    $thankyouurl = "https://example.com/thanks.php" ;

    $message =

    // FORM FIELDS
    "Name: $name\n\n" .
    "Dropdown: $dropdown\n\n" .
    "E-mail: $email\n\n" . ;

    mail($mailto, $from, $message,
    "From: <$mailto>" . $headersep . "Reply-To: <$mailto>" . $headersep );

    // AUTORESPONDER SENDER NAME AND EMAIL 
    $myname = "Organization";
    $mymail = "noreply@example.com";

    // AUTORESPONDER SUBJECT 
    $respond_subject = Subject";

    // AUTORESPONDER MESSAGE
    $respond_message = "Message
    ";

    $headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\nFrom: $myname <$mymail>\nReply-To: 
    <$mymail>\nReturn-Path: <$mymail>\nX-Mailer: PHP";

    // THIS IS THE AUTORESPONDER
    mail($email, $respond_subject, $respond_message, $headers);

    header( "Location: $thankyouurl" );
```

Comment: `$respond_message =file_get_contents( --my file -- )`.  DO NOT accept a file URL or string from the form as this value!  Pass a code 1-n and use a switch or array to set the mail template file name.  Otherwise you have set up a spambot relay.

Comment: $respond_message is just some default text in the '"mailer" file.

Comment: If changing that text is not your question then please edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: Sorry if the original post wasn't clear. When the form is submitted, the form "action" triggers a PHP file (what I'm calling the "mailer" file) which does three things: it sends the submitted form data to my e-mail address, it sends a thank you e-mail to the form submitter, and it redirects the form submitter to a thank you page. What I'm trying to do is have several different "mailer" files. The one that is triggered is based on which option the form submitter chooses from the form's drop-down menu. (Different options selected require different thank you emails and different thank you pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar post on Stack that included a solution that I used successfully.

PHP FORM

```
     <script>
     function chgAction(){
     $('#form1').attr({'action':$('option:selected').attr('data-action')});
     $('#form1').submit();
     }
     </script>

     <form  id="form1" name="form1" action="/" method="post" >

     <label for="dropdown">
     <span>Which of the following:</span>
     <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onChange="javascript:chgAction()"  >
     <option label=""></option>
     <option data-action="https://example.com/mailer.php" value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
     <option data-action="https://example.com/mailer2.php" value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
     <option data-action="https://example.com/mailer3.php" value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
     </select>
     </label>
```